# Links css underline

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, underline

I have the following style for my footers in my css file:

```
#footer { 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .7em;
    color:#000000;
}
```

This is the html for the footer part:

```
<div id="footer">
   <br> //google ad
   <br>
   <br>
   <A HREF="http://www.site1.com">Blog</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A     
   HREF="http://site1/rss.xml">RSS</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A 
   HREF="http://www.mexautos.com">Autos Usados</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A 
   HREF="http://www.site2">Videos Chistosos</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A 
   HREF="http:/s.blogspot.com">Fotos de Chavas</A><br>
   Derechos Reservados &copy; 2008-<?=date('Y')?> address<br>
</div>
```

But for some reason some of the links show underlined.

Any ideas how I can make it so the links do not appear underlined?

Thx

Comment: you're hurting my eyes with uppercase tags :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can try

```
#footer a { text-decoration: none }
```

that means all <a> tags within the element with id footer will have no underline.

Comment: Argh damnit, you were faster^^

Comment: I might be being unnecessarily "nitpicky" - but not necessarily all a tags...something with a higher specificity could override what you put above. I have ran into problems with this before and could never figure out why it didn't work. Just an FYI.

Comment: to have the highest specificity, we need <a style="text-decoration: none">click me</a> but usually that's not recommended unless we really need to.

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
#footer a{ 
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Apply the following style:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've intentionally given you complete coverage of all the states that an `<a>` tag can have, but you very well may be able to get away with the following as well:

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Finally, if you only want this applied to the footer:

```
#footer a, #footer a:link, #footer a:visited, #footer a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I'd highly recommend installing Firebug in Firefox as it allows you to see what classes are applied and it what order - essentially helping you to debug your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your stylesheet:

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
```